# Get fuse version installed on current OS

Tags: python, linux, fuse

I have to build installer in Linux. First step of the installer is to identify the fuse version. If the version is bigger than required than proceed with install process.

How can I get the fuse version using Python?

Regards,
Ivgi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least on my system, `fusermount -V` gives the current version of Fuse.

So something like:

```
with os.popen('fusermount -V') as p:
    versiontext = p.read()
#do something with version text
```

should work.